# Data from Postgres Production DB to a postgres staging database

Tags: postgresql, load, scheduling, data-transfer, pega

Our team has a postgres DB which has a lot of data, to which Pega (Decisioning Platform) is connected. But Pega receives unwanted attributes, data and irrelevant information from this DB which is impacting its performance and efficiency. I'm planning to implement a staging DB(another postgres DB) with only required tables, data and attributes for Pega. Could you please suggest a best possible solution to load data from Postgres DB to this staging DB on a regular basis. I guess one best option would be ETL. Are there any other easy efficient ways of doing the same.

Comment: 1) [Logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html). 2) [postgres-fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html).

Comment: You have provided insufficient details upon which to base an opinion or recommendations. As presented, this is also not a programming problem but instead a system design issue.